# Should there be a viewing-order tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, suggested-order

There's already a [reading-order tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-order) that seems to be quite popular. There've also been a few questions (like [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/where-to-start-with-dr-who)) that are about the order to view a long series in (in this case, Dr Who). It seems obvious to me that if reading-order is a valid tag (and it seems that it is), then viewing-order would be equally valid (although I don't have enough rep to create it myself).

Should somebody create a viewing-order tag, or are reading-order and viewing-order similar enough that they should be combined into a single tag, like 'chronology' or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, seems alright to me.  I wish I could think of an even more encompassing term, but I'm at a loss for the moment.

Comment: Created. If we get a lot of disagreement -- or an umbrella term less cumbersome than reading-and-viewing-order -- we can change it.

Answer (score 17):

How about suggested-order? Make them all tag synonyms of each other, so that suggested-order'll win out in the end?

Comment: I'm down with a suggested-order tag, I'm just undecided on whether or not we should created synonyms. On one hand it would be nice because all of them would be in one suggested-order pile, and we wouldn't have to have multiple tags for different media types. But on the other hand, some people maybe only interested in one form of media. Then again that's just a guess.

Comment: When I created reading-order (http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/282/acceptability-of-reading-viewing-order-questions) I hoped that someone could come up with a media-generic term.  suggested-order works for me.